# What's the difference between a string and a user entered string in C

Tags: c, string, scanf, strdup

I'm using with a smaller piece of code to test functionality for a larger (beginner) program, but I don't understand the difference between two strings.

I found and used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

char *string, *found;

string = strdup ("1/2/3");
printf("Orig: '%s'\n",string);

while ((found = strsep(&string,"/")) != NULL )
  printf ("%s\n",found);

return (0);
}
```

and this print the tokens one at a time.

Then when I try and move to a user entered string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char string[13],
  char *found, *cp = string;

  fprintf(stderr, "\nEnter string: ");
  scanf("%12s",string);
  printf("Original string: '%s'\n",string);

  while((found =  strsep(&cp,"/,-")) != NULL )
    printf("%s\n",found);

  return(0);
}
```

I get a seg fault. I understand the basics of pointers, arrays and strings, but clearly I'm missing something, and would love for someone to tell me what it is!

Also - if I change `printf("%s\n",found);` to `printf("%i\n",found);` I get some junk integers returned, but always the correct amount, e.g. If I enter `1/2/3` I get three lines of integers, `1111/2222` I get two lines.

Thanks!

-Edit- 
 There was an adittional problem with `strsep`, detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394350/string-token-from-strsep-not-printing-seg-fault/49394489?noredirect=1#comment85793882_49394489). Thanks all.

Comment: You need to allocate space for the user-defined string.  The string literal knows how long it is.

Comment: Seem like there is a guy mass-downvoting without telling why. Cool. This will help to improv us (because I don't understand why I was downvoted).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I remember reading about this so just wrapping my head around it. In the meantime, I tried everyone's suggestion of fixing the size but I still get a seg fault! Updating question to reflect this.

Comment: Also, I've not voted on anyone's answer yet so I'll be sure to do it once I've understood everything. Hopefully it'll help counter the downvoter!

Comment: Update - I changed the specifier in printf to `printf("%p\n",found);` and I get three addresses output so strsep id doing it's work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first piece of code, `string` is assigned the return value of `strdup`, which allocates space for the string to duplicate and returns a pointer to that allocated space.

In the second piece of code, `string` uninitialized when it is passed to `scanf`, so `scanf` is reading the invalid value in that pointer and attempting to dereference it.  This invokes  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case manifests as a crash.

You need to set aside space for the user's string.  A simple way to do this is to create an array of a given size:

```
char string[80];
```

Then tell `scanf` how many characters it can read in:

```
 scanf("%79s",string);
```

Comment: Thanks, a very nicely presented answer that reminded me of how pointers work. For some reason the string won't print, even after correcting the length of `string`!

Comment: @William If you have `cp` declared as a `char *` it should work.  Your example currently has it as `char`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and input. No, it was my typo in the question, I had the `*` in my code. For clarity I think I'll start a new question regarding this other problem, and keep this for the original mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Differences between the two cases:

1. In the first case `string` points to valid memory that was allocated by `strdup` while in the second case you are trying to read into invalid memory.
2. The first case is well behaved while the second case is cause for undefined behavior.

The second case can be fixed by allocating memory for it using `malloc` or using a fixed size array.

```
char *string,*found;
string = malloc(100); // Make it large enough for your need.
fprintf(stderr, "\nEnter string: ");
scanf("%99s",string);
```

or

```
char string[100], *found;
fprintf(stderr, "\nEnter string: ");
scanf("%99s",string);
```

---

Make sure you deallocate dynamically allocated memory. Otherwise, your program leaks memory.

Comment: Thanks, I remember now the pointer goes to whatever was in the memory. Strangely I still get seg faults even after allocating the length.

Comment: You are not passing the correct argument to `strsep`. Use `char* cp = string; while((found =  strsep(&cp,"/,-")) != NULL )`.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that! The code now progresses past the strsep (I put a simple `printf` line in after it) but seg faults on the `printf("%s\n",found);` line. There's something I'm still not spotting!

Comment: @William, I can't explain why that's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You should allocate memory for the user input string.

First option is statically

`char string[256];`

and second option is dynamically using `malloc()` function

```
char *string;

string = (char*) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
if (string == NULL)
   {
   //error
   }
```

Don't forget at the end to release the allocated memory

```
free(string);
```

Comment: what's the purpose of doing a malloc like that ? You can just type "char string[256]" and the result will be the same.

Comment: It's just a second way to allocate memory. What's wrong with that?

Comment: and in the original code the first string is mallocd by strdup.

Comment: Because in your example, you seem to free it rigth after. So what's the purpose of this allocation ? It add complexity to the code, for nothing. But I didn't read that you put the statically form, sorry. (and sizeof(char) == 1, so no need to add it, and if you really want a sizeof, it's better to have "sizeof(*string)  )

Comment: You are right about sizeof(char) is equal to 1, just to be typical and not risk to confuse the OP. I added the free() to remember put it at the end of the code to release the allocated memory

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allocate the space needed !
You have to have a memory space to write to.
You can have it statically "char string[256]", or dynamically with allocation.

In your first example, you use "strdup" that does a malloc, but scanf will not allocate memory for you.

If you want all the user input, you usually wrap the scanf in a while loop in order to retrieve the user input chunk by chunk. Then you have to reallocate each time your buffer is insuffisante to add the chunk.

If you just want to retrieve a string from stdin without doing any format-checking, I strongly recommand fgets.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is very simple. Your `string` variable is a char pointer and you need to allocate memory to it to store a string.Probably in your first case `strdup ("1/2/3");` returns a string and your `char pointer *string` points to the string return by `strdup` function and that is the reason why you are not getting the segmentation error in the first case. Even in your first case also you might get a segmentation error if enter a very long string.

so allocate enough memory to the `string` pointer like below in your second example and that will fix your problem:-

```
 char *string = malloc(50);// here malloc will allocate 50 bytes from heap
```

Answer (score 0):

In user enter string case you do not have memory allocated to the pointer string.In the first case, **strdup** is allocating memory for string pointer while in the second case you do not have any memory associated with string pointer leading to segfault. first, allocate memory using **malloc** and then use **scanf**.

Answer (score 0):

char string[13]
char cp=string

Here cp is a variable of type char and as 1 byte of memory allocated

It won't be able to store a char array of 13 character which would be 13 bytes, and it's because of this you are getting segmentation fault

Comment: Ok, that's interesting, I thought char *cp was a pointer? When I change `printf("%s\n",found);` argument to `%i` I get (random) integers, and it return the correct number of tokens I am expecting so I thought the whole string was being passed correctly